# IE adds [1] to filename asp.net on file opening(c#)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I'm sending an excel file with http response and IE adds a [1] to the end of the filename when "Open" is clicked. On "Save" file it doesn't. Is there a way to fix it?

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename+".xlsx");             
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";  
response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
response.BinaryWrite(pkg.GetAsByteArray()); //pkg is ExcelPackage 
response.End();
```

Comment: I think the problem is that when you click "Open", the file has to be saved to a temporary folder, but a file with that same name already exists so it adds "[1]" to make it unique.

Comment: David, Are you talking about temporary internet files folder? there is no file with such a name. I've tried giving a random "jsfljasldfgdflskj" filename, and it does the same thing.

Comment: Does the filename has dots in it? Check the 2nd answer here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7e40f007-7339-4b95-9159-3be6cec100a3/ie-adds-square-brackets-while-downloading-file?forum=ieitpropriorver

Comment: thank you, no the filename doesnot contain dots except for the dot before the extension

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely doing that because you've already opened the file once (or possibly you have opened another file with the same name), so it has saved a copy of it for viewing. The `[1]` is just there to avoid naming conflicts in your temporary internet files folder.

This is something which is done entirely on the client, so I doubt there will be any way to do this in server-side code.

Comment: There is no file with such a name. Filename is generated based on dates.It always adds [1] regardless of how many times you open same file, the number is not incremented as when you save a file.